# Is there any way to remove my share extension app switch on/off option from device default shared UIActivityController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, share-extension

I am developing a share iOS extension app which will support the share a file or text contents to other app through device shared UIActivityController.
My iOS extension app have included the required keys into plist for a share extension app:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                    <true/>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
            <string>MainInterface</string>
            <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
        </dict>
```

I want to hide on/off switch appearance from Default device Activities for my share app. I think, i am missing some share extension key(s) into plist to hide the switch on/off from Activity screen. Could someone know that keys? Please help me. 
Note that I have checked 'KeepLock' iOS app and app has hidden the switch appearance from device activities screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you found anything?